# How/where to go for a stock market index (aggregate) API or other method to accessing

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I'm attempting to install a stock market gauge displaying the S&P 500, NASDAQ, and DJIA composite indices; however, I'm not sure where to find sources to gather the three together.  Otherwise, I think I could bring it in one at a time as the following:

```
yahoo_url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^GSPC" 
web.DataReader('^GSPC','yahoo')  # S&P 500
```

I'm not too sure how to go about making this particular code work though. 
Any advice or pointing in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
AJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List the indexes you want
`indexes = ['^DJI', '^GSPC', '^IXIC']`

Query yahoo finance for them

`df = web(indexes, 'yahoo', start='2010-01-01')`

```
>>> df.columns
MultiIndex([('Adj Close',  '^DJI'),
            ('Adj Close', '^GSPC'),
            ('Adj Close', '^IXIC'),
            (    'Close',  '^DJI'),
            (    'Close', '^GSPC'),
            (    'Close', '^IXIC'),
            (     'High',  '^DJI'),
            (     'High', '^GSPC'),
            (     'High', '^IXIC'),
            (      'Low',  '^DJI'),
            (      'Low', '^GSPC'),
            (      'Low', '^IXIC'),
            (     'Open',  '^DJI'),
            (     'Open', '^GSPC'),
            (     'Open', '^IXIC'),
            (   'Volume',  '^DJI'),
            (   'Volume', '^GSPC'),
            (   'Volume', '^IXIC')],
           names=['Attributes', 'Symbols'])
```

Comment: This is great!  Thank you for your help, Kenan!

Comment: Glad I could help `+1`